# Decimal places in JS

Tags: javascript

I have two form inputs which display the calculated invoice sub-total and total of a form.

The problem I'm having is it's not displaying 2 decimal places.

Subtotal function:

```
function calcProdSubTotal() {        
    var prodSubTotal = 0;    
    $(".row-total-input").each(function(){        
        var valString = $(this).val() || 0;            
        prodSubTotal += parseInt(valString);                        
    });            
    $("#product-subtotal").val(prodSubTotal);    
};
```

Total function

```
function calcOrderTotal() {

    var orderTotal = 0;

    var productSubtotal = $("#product-subtotal").val() || 0;
    var productTax = $("#product-tax").val() || 0;
        
    var orderTotal = parseInt(productSubtotal) + parseInt(productTax);
    var orderTotalNice = "$" + orderTotal;
    
    $("#order-total").val(orderTotalNice);
        
};
```

How do I go about displaying two decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$("#product-subtotal").val(prodSubTotal);`

to `$("#product-subtotal").val(addDecimals(prodSubTotal));`

and change `$("#product-subtotal").val(prodSubTotal);`

to `$("#product-subtotal").val(addDecimals(prodSubTotal));`

```
function addDecimals(a){
     a += "";
     var i=a.indexOf('.');
    if(i<0){
        return a + ".00";
    }
    var j = a.substring(i);
    console.log(j);
    if(j.length<3){
        for(var k=j.length;k<3;k++)
            a+='0';
        return a;
    }   
    if(j.length>3){
        return a.substring(0, i)+j.substring(0,3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look here:
http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html

Basically you can use `toFixed(2)`, but then you get some rounding.

Or, if rounding is bad you can do `parseInt(productTax * 100) / 100`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with real numbers it would be better to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. To format the number you could use the `toFixed` function:

```
$("#product-subtotal").val(prodSubTotal.toFixed(2));
```